# How to convert String time to date time in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to match with current time with predefined time but i got stuck in matching because those are in string .
This is my Code

```
$scope.TimeString = "17:00-21:00,7:00-10:00,9:45-12:00";
 $scope.currentTime = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'HH:mm');
$scope.IsItemAvailable = function (timeString) {

                var tempTimeArray = "";
                tempTimeArray = timeString.split(",");
                for (var i = 0; i < tempTimeArray.length; i++) {
                    var tempTime = tempTimeArray[i];
                    var itemTime = tempTime.split("-")
                    var fromTime = $filter('date')(itemTime[0], 'HH:mm');
                    var toTime = $filter('date')(itemTime[1], 'HH:mm');
                if ($scope.currentTime >= fromTime && $scope.currentTime <= toTime) {
                        $scope.isAvailable = true;
                        break;

                    }
                    else {

                        $scope.isAvailable = false;
                    }
}
it's returning false always.Any please help me to acheive it.
```

Comment: Your wrong is `$filter('date')('9:45', 'HH:mm')` It's not work obviously.

Comment: @vp_arth.then how to convert string to Datetime?

Comment: If you can convert  your times to zero-padded: `09:55` - you can compare it as strings(if you have not midnight included intervals).

Comment: `Date::setHours` and `Date::setMinutes` can be used for this

Comment: @vp_arth `Date::setHours` and `Date::setMinutes` allow to set date component.

Comment: @vp_arth.It's working perfectly..Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AvantikaSaini, it still useful if you use same date for both to compare. `var from = new Date(0,0,0)` for example.

Comment: @vp_arth yes in that case it does. But the answer your provided is a better option i believe

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your times to zero-padded: `09:55` then you can compare it as strings(if you have not midnight included intervals).

Else you can convert `hh:mm` to minutes number and then compare:

```
var cur = $scope.currentTime.split(':');
var from = itemTime[0].split(':');
var to   = itemTime[1].split(':');
cur  =  cur[0]*60+ cur[1];
from = from[0]*60+from[1];
to   =   to[0]*60+  to[1];
if (cur >= from && cur <= to) {
  // available
}
```

Some DRY resolved:

```
var times = [$scope.currentTime, itemTime[0], itemTime[1]];
  times.map(interval => interval.split(':'))
       .map(interval => interval[0]*60 + interval[1]);
if (times[0] >= times[1] && times[0] <= times[2]) {
   // available
}
```